# Track who completed the videos on SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, reports, video

I have uploaded training videos for us internally on SharePoint Online and I would like to know if it's possible to generate a report that shows us who are the employees that **watched** and **completed** the videos.

I know that we can see the views insights but it does not provide insight if the employee completed the video.

[image]

Example: If the video length is 10mins and the employee watched 5 mins it should show us that the employee completed 50% of the video, and he watched all the video so it will be 100% and status as completed.

Is there any API that gives us those kinds of insights for the employee that watched any video and is there any API to extract the viewer's data provided on the file?

Any advice is highly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly how SP Online presents videos, but if you can get a reference to the video element as an [`HTMLMediaElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement), there is a pretty good API you can use to hook into events such as `ended` when the full video ends or `paused` if it enters the pause state before reaching the end, and then properties like `currentTime` you could use to find out what time the video was paused.

This is all presuming you can get JavaScript running on the page where your video(s) is/are.  SPFx web part, maybe?

And then of course you would have to store all that analytic data somewhere.